# Table Layout Beamer

Tags: tables, beamer, graphics

I need to create a structure which is similar to Table Layout in the presentation (Beamer). I have rows, and in every row I have some columns (pictures,text).

E.g., I mean this:

[image]

I need only to locate text and images on the slide (I don't need borders).

How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: Using several `columns` environment on the same frame?

Comment: I know about colums, but what about rows?

Comment: You should use one `columns` environment per row!

Comment: I mean what about the case when I need to place 3 lines and one picture? (see the updated text).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick google search, gave [this](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2005-4/mertz/mertz.pdf).

I just copied the first example. Two "\columns" within the column environment "\begin{column}... \end{column}" gives you - who would have thought - two columns in one row. Just repeat this for a second row with two columns.

The \framebox around the image is optional and all you need to do is play with the widths of the columns (the 1.5in) and the image size.

```
\begin{frame}
 \frametitle{Two Column Output}

 \begin{columns}[c]
   \column{1.5in}
   Practical \TeX\ 2005\\
   Practical \TeX\ 2005\\
   Practical \TeX\ 2005

   \column{1.5in}
   \framebox{\includegraphics[width=1.in]{image}}
 \end{columns}

 \begin{columns}[c]
   \column{1.5in}
   Practical \TeX\ 2005\\
   Practical \TeX\ 2005\\
   Practical \TeX\ 2005

   \column{1.5in}
   \framebox{\includegraphics[width=1.in]{image}}
 \end{columns}

\end{frame}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, now I see, it is necessary to use \column

Comment: This does not look as nice as you shown if text and images have different sizes. In my case I have 2 columns, each starts with text and have a picture below. There is a different amount of text which causes the pictures in the columns are not aligned vertically.