# How can add a logo in plain frame?

Tags: beamer, mini-frames

I generate a presentation file with `beamer` class.

And in a specify frame, I must use plain option, but it remove my logo.

How can I add again my logo on this plain frame?

I used this code:

```
{

\logo{\includegraphics[height=0.7cm]{mylogo}}

\begin{frame}[plain]

\centering
\Huge
\textbf{{\only<1>{\color{orange}}\\[1.5cm] Thank you for listening\\
}}
\end{frame}
}
```

But the logo not show in my frame.

Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: maybe a file not found bug --- extension is missing

Comment: have compiled it now --- your textbf works but your modification regarding includegraphics does not work --- care about path, file name and file extension

Comment: No, my path is right I use the same for global. And other frame without plain option, logo still show normal.

Comment: ok, you can use colums command and includegraphics for instance to place the graphic. you should know the desired position of your "logo" if plain is a requirement.

Comment: Please help me more detail. can you send me some example code, i think it more easier to know.

Answer (score 1):

This solution does not use `\logo` command since it gives way to `[plain]`. Instead,  a way via `pgfpicture` from `pgf` is utilized.  The following command

```
\begin{pgfpicture}{<start x>}{<start y>}{<end x>}{<end y>}
```

sets the picture range. You could have set them 0 and tune the coordinate of `\pgfxy{(<x,y>)}` to suit your need.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgf} % make sure you use this!
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]

\begin{pgfpicture}{0}{0}{2cm}{2cm}
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(-4.4,0)}{\pgfimage[width=0.5\textwidth]{crocuses.jpg}} 
\end{pgfpicture}
\centering
\Huge
\textbf{{\only<1>{\color{orange}}\\[1.5cm] Thank you for listening\\
}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a group together with the `\logo` command. Have tried it now with `plain` instead of `Szeged`. It works.

In this case, it was the title frame. Works also with `plain` (if you meant empty) frames.

```
{ %start group
 \logo{\includegraphics[scale=0.41]{pic/your_logo.jpg}}
 \frame{ \titlepage }
} %end group
```

Tadaa with an empty frame

```
{ %start group
 \logo{\includegraphics[scale=0.41]{pic/your_logo.jpg}}
 \frame{    }
} %end group
```

Another option would be to place it with columns. [SE TeX url](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68572/table-layout-beamer)

See subsequent code which shows how to place manually a picture / logo / graphic.

```
\begin{frame}[plain]
\begin{center}

Thanks for ..........\\

\begin{figure}{\includegraphics[width=1.in]{pic/your_logo.jpg}}\end{figure}

\end{center}
\end{frame}
```

The layout is your task.

Comment: It still not working with my example

Comment: @phuong concerning my code --- it works with mactex and miktex

Comment: No, if you use \frame[plain], the logo not show in this frame. I also use miktex. Please add option plain as my example, you'll see that

Comment: correct. then avoid [plain]. :-) or place it old school without logo command.

Comment: My problem is i want to remove headline and footnote but i don't want to change background image. I used \setbeamertemplate{footline}{}, \setbeamertemplate{header}{}  but it remove a head and foot of background. I used plain option because it can avoid remove back ground but it remove my logo. Please help me

Comment: check out the addendum